# Clang: Using Cmake to build a compile_commands.json for my project

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create the compile_commands.json file by following these instructions: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html

I don't see any option on the docs that allows be to build the compile_commands.json file against my own code. The command that I use when I follow the doc builds the json file, but the contents of the file contains files/directories in the llvm source directory. I'm assuming that if this file contains contents of my own project, then when I run run-clang-tidy.py (from [here](https://www.kdab.com/clang-tidy-part-1-modernize-source-code-using-c11c14/)), then it will run clang-tidy against my own project.

So the question: How do I get Cmake to build the compile_commands.json to contain my own project?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear exactly what you want to achieve. In the link you provided, the author is building LLVM from source code, which is why the compilation database (`compile_commands.json`) refers to those sources.

In general to build the compilation database while building the source tree with CMake, you provide it with the `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON` flag.

So, where the blog post you linked calls

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON path/to/llvm/sources
```

...you would exchange the path to the sources for your own source tree:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON this/is/my/source/tree/path
```

...which should generate the json-file in the current (build) directory.
As in the article, you will probably want to symlink that file to the root of your source tree and then run your tools from there.

Here's a (very) simple build script that I wrote and sometimes use. Maybe it can be helpful to you (adjust to your own needs obviously). It should be run from the root of your source tree.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

type=Debug
if ! [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
  type="$1"
  mkdir -p build/$type
  shift
fi

# Configure build
cmake -S . -B build/$type -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$type .

# Build
cmake --build build/$type --parallel 4 --config $type "$@"

ln -fs build/$type/compile_commands.json .
```